# Multiple BackgroundWorkers c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a server application which uses two BackgroundWorkers:

1) Used to constantly check if the SVN repository was updated.

2) Used for managing a queue of processes.

```
BackgroundWorker revisionsWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
revisionsWorker.DoWork += (queueSender1, queueEvent1) => checkRevision();
revisionsWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

BackgroundWorker queueWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
queueWorker.DoWork += (queueSender2, queueEvent2) => manageComputersQueue();
queueWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

When the SVN is updated, the function `checkRevision()` updates the local repository, runs some scripts, and compiles a solution using `devenv.com`.
The `queueWorker` checks if the server is busy running the `checkRevision()`. If it's not busy, it runs the processes according to their place in the queue.

My problem is that if the SVN was updated, and the `checkRevision()` is running (takes some time..) the `manageComputersQueue()` is not accessed at any time, until `checkRevision()` is finished.

Meaning, I want the `manageComputersQueue()` to run always, and if the server is busy doing other tasks, it will notify the client that the server is currently busy.

Is it possible that when 1 backgroundworker is doing some stuff, other backgroundworkers are waiting for it to finish even if they all run asynchronously?

Comment: Are the backgroundworkers using a shared resource (such as the UI thread to report progress, a file, a lock, ...)?

Comment: There is a global boolean indicating the server is still alive `m_serverAlive`. Both `checkRevision()` and `manageComputersQueue()` run in: `while (m_serverAlive)` loop. They don't share other resources.

Comment: Did you have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694271/c-sharp-multiple-backgroundworkers (not completing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `BackgroundWorker` + `*ResetEvent`, but it will be a bit clunky.

Consider using [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd321405.aspx)

Comment: I think that Task.ContinueWith will wait for one of them to finish and then run the second one, am I right? If so, then it's not quite what I wish to achieve. I want them both running asynchronously always - meaning that even if one of them is busy, the other one is still running. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It will create a chain of tasks. I think I didn't get it, is it not what you try to achieve? You say *"Is it possible that when 1 backgroundworker is doing some stuff, other backgroundworkers are waiting for it to finish even if they all run asynchronously?"*

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to subscribe `RunWorkerCompleted` event - which means you dont have anything to report to UI thread.
In that case just use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => checkRevision() )
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => manageComputersQueue() )
```

They should not conflict with each other unless you have some explicit logic within those methods which blocks on one another.