# C# Keep track of the amount of written bytes

Tags: c#, wpf, file, byte

I was looking into writing data and I used:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, GetBytes());
```

This worked for me but then I wanted to get the progress of the written bytes so I can have a progressbar added to it. I found out that my method can't connect to a progressbar so I decided to use this:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))) {
            byte[] nextBytes = GetBytes(); // your logic to get what to write;
            writer.Write(nextBytes);
        }
```

This writes my file succesfully but after a lot of searching (maybe not enough) I can't seem to find out how to keep track of the amount of bytes being written until it's complete. Maybe I'm using a wrong method, if anyone could help me out, would be awesome! (I use a WPF)

Thanks in advance,

**Update:**

On top of the project I delcare BackgroundWorker()

```
    BackgroundWorker bw;
```

Then when I start the download I haev this:

```
bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);

            bw.RunWorkerAsync(data);
```

My doWork method:

```
        private void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        downloadData data = (downloadData) e.Argument;
        _source = data.DownloadLocation + @"\";

        sem.WaitOne();

        //enters
        updateStatusBar("- Downloading -", data, 0);
        Video vid = youtube.GetVideo(data.Url);
        byte[] bytes = vid.GetBytes();

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(_source + vid.FullName, FileMode.Create))) {

            // do your read logic here and read into bytes

            var bytesLeft = bytes.Length;
            var bytesWritten = 0;
            while (bytesLeft > 0) {
                int chunk = Math.Min(64, bytesLeft);

                writer.Write(bytes, bytesWritten, chunk);
                bytesWritten += chunk;
                bytesLeft -= chunk;

                // calculate progress bar status
                bw.ReportProgress(bytesWritten * 100 / bytes.Length, data);
            }
        }
        // Leaves
        updateStatusBar("- Done -", data, 100);

        sem.Release();
    }
```

My Progresschanged method:

```
    private void bw_ProgressChanged (object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        YoutubeData data = (YoutubeData) e.UserState;
        updateStatusBar("Downloading: " + e.ProgressPercentage, data, e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```

Method for updating status bar:

```
        private void updateStatusBar(string txt, downloadData data, int progress) {
        _downloadData.Remove(data);
        data.ProgressText = txt;
        data.Status = progress;
        _downloadData.Add(data);

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            lv_DownloadData.ItemsSource = null;
            lv_DownloadData.ItemsSource = _youtubeData;
        }));
    }
```

But now it freezes my WPF.

Comment: Look for using `BackgroundWorker` class. It would be an easy way to achieve that.

Comment: Stream.Write() always writes the entire bytes.

Comment: "I can't seem to keep track of the amount of bytes being written until it's complete": I don't see any attempt to do that in the code you're sharing. Is that the problem?

Comment: You could wrap your `GetBytes` method by sticking it on a class, which keeps track of the number of bytes returned by it. Then you could pull 'TotalBytesWritten' off this object using a property.

Comment: @bakala12 Does that work with multiple files?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, I can't seem to find out how to keep track of the amount of bytes being written. Sorry if my post was unclear.

Comment: @JoshC If you keep a running count in a private field belonging to the class, it will work with multiple files. That is to say, when you add two integers, the runtime AI does an elaborate check and if one of the values you're adding happens to be a number of bytes you just wrote to a disk, it permits you to add the two numbers. Otherwise, of course, all addition in C# produces either random numbers or zero.

Comment: @JoshC What did you try? Tell us what you tried. Did you try addition? Subtraction? Multiplication? What did you *try*?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I tried multiplication while writing the bytes but it only returned the total amount of bytes that are written in the end.

Comment: @JoshC "It" returned. What "it"? "I did something somewhere, not sure what, but it returned a number": And you want me to debug that for you. What was it about multiplication that struck you as a particularly appropriate way to add numbers?

Comment: @EdPlunkett "it" is the variable I used to get the count of the amount of bytes being written. I found out why I only got the total amount because I was initializing the variable after the method wrote my file.

Comment: @JoshC The fundamental problem here is that you had a bug with the code you were using to keep track of the total, *and you refused to show anybody that code*. You showed us other code. "My car broke down, here's my bicycle, can you see the problem?" No, nobody can see the problem, because the problem is in your car, and we have no access to your car. Can you follow what I'm saying?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah I follow what you are saying. My intention of the post is to find out a way of keeping track of the amount of bytes while being written. Unfortunatly I don't have the code I had so I had to give you a "bike" instead of my "car".

Comment: @JoshC Well, if you don't have access to your own code, you've got bigger problems than distinguishing multiplication from addition.

Answer (score 4):

Write bytes in chunks and use a `BackgroundWorker`

```
    using(var writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)))) {

       // do your read logic here and read into bytes

        var bytesLeft = bytes.Length;
        var bytesWritten = 0;
        while(bytesLeft > 0) {
            int chunk = Math.Min(64, bytesLeft);
            writer.WriteBytes(array, bytesWritten, chunk);
            bytesWritten += chunk;
            bytesLeft -= chunk;

            // calculate progress bar status
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(bytesWritten * 100 / array.Length);
        }
    }
```

**Update**

OK, this is purely untested.. but stay we me..
Each `BinaryWriter`will do its work on a `BackgroundWorker`

so you set up the background worker

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
```

Then you need to start the `BackgroundWorker` somewhere using `bw.RunWorkerAsync()`

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your task here

     // report its progress
    bw.ReportProgress(..); 
}

void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // update your progress bar here

}
```

Comment: How can I do this so it can handle x number of files?

Comment: @JoshC you are going to do it serially right? means showing progress of 1 file and then when its over showing the next one?

Comment: No, I have more than one file at the same time.

Comment: so you have multiple binary writers on seperate threads all being written to simultaneosly?

Comment: Yeah up to a max of 2 or 3.

Comment: @JoshC and you want to see all progress bar's on a single form?

Comment: Yes, I use a listview for that. Each download has it's own row in Listview

Comment: are you using `c#` 4 or higher? I mean just from the point of view whether you can use `async / await` or `TPL`

Comment: Yes I am using C# higher than 4

Comment: Pressed enter on accident, but yeh is it not possible to update at backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(bytesWritten * 100 / array.Length); instead of calling backgroundworker?

Comment: @JoshC _instead of calling backgroundworker?_ I'm sorry I didn't get you there. Basically you do your % calculation and feed it to `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` when you call this method it raises the `ProgressChanged` event

Comment: Oh sorry, Instead of the line `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` you just update the progressbar with the content. I tried this but somehow the code seems to be really slow and it takes forever to download a file.

Comment: @JoshC when you call the `bw.RunWorkerAsync()` the `BackgroundWorker` spawns a new thread and runs it in the background, the method `bw_DoWork` is called on this thread, now you do your long running task here and you shouldn't update the GUI in this method since updating the GUI takes much longer it should be done in the `ProgressChanged` event handler. which is typically subscribed by your `Form` so that event would run on the GUI thread.

Comment: I use a listview for my downloads and every download has it's own progressbar. I change the value via a `{Binding Status}` on the progressbar, I will update my post so you can understand what I'm saying.

Comment: @JoshC currently what kind of problems are you facing? Are the downloads working ok is only the GUI part giving trouble ? I mean only the progress bar part?

Comment: Yeah, only the progress bar part is giving me trouble.

Comment: @JoshC what library are you using for Youtube? I see that you are already using `Thread` for each download. Then you do `vid.GetBytes()` and this gets a small part of the video, right? If you do end up using `BackgroundWorker` you would not need to use `Thread`. The `BackgroundWorker` will start downloading the video on another thread and will report progress too. Also do you know the size of the video at the start? you would need that to calculate your download progress?

Comment: I use LibVideo, `vid.GetBytes()` gets all the bytes of the video. Is it possible to limit the amount of `BackgroundWorker`s? What would you recommend doing for the download? Because to report the progress to the progressbar I need to know what progressbar it's using. In my code I call `downloadData` to get and set the status.

Comment: @JoshC ... contd. from above ... You say you are getting the whole video in the `vid.GetBytes()` call what if the video is 1GB in size you be hit a memory limit then ...

Comment: How can I get the data from `downloadData ` with `bw.RunWorkerAsync()` in the `DoWork` method? Same goes with `ProgressChanged` method.

Comment: @JoshC deleted my older commend as it was wrong ... in fact you can pass your data to `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` and then get it in the `DoWork` method. Why don't you keep data in a class level variable that's also an option..

Comment: How do I get the object I sent with `RunWorkerAsync(Object)`? I tried `downloadData data = (downloadData) sender;` but that got me an error:

Comment: Error: Could not convert to the type `downloadData`

Comment: Okay, got that part working via `e.Argument`. But checking when progress has changed doesn't have an `e.Argument` and I get the error I got before when using sender as the object.

Comment: @JoshC `,DoWorkEventArgs e)`... `(downloadData) e.Argument`

Comment: Okay got that to work. But now the problem is that when updating the progressbar my WPF freezes. And nothing happens.

Comment: @JoshC you don't need to send `downloadData` to `ProgressEvent` just send the progress..

Comment: @JoshC post your new code, remove all the semaphores et al for now just the basic code , BGW, video download and progress bar/ listview

Comment: But to be able to update the progressbar I need `downloadData`. `
            YoutubeData data = (YoutubeData) e.UserState;
            _youtubeData.Remove(data);
            data.ProgressText = "Downloading: " + e.ProgressPercentage;
            data.Status = e.ProgressPercentage;
            _youtubeData.Add(data);
            
            lv_DownloadData.ItemsSource = null;
            lv_DownloadData.ItemsSource = _youtubeData;`

Comment: Oh, thought it would look better, will update the post in a sec.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: @JoshC In `updateStatusBar` why do you keep removing and then re-adding `data`?

Comment: @JoshC there are many shortcomings in the code, you have only 1 `BackgroundWorker` what  happens if you want to parallely download another file? you would need another BGW then so you may have to create your BGW's dynamically. ...

Comment: Can you update your post with what I should do - example code -? For me this is the first time using a BackgroundWorker and progressbars.

Comment: @JoshC take some inspiration from this code [Multiple Background Workers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694271/c-sharp-multiple-backgroundworkers)

Comment: @JoshC I suggest you do this whole project in steps, 1st try to get 1 file downloading with the progress bar and then move on to multiple files

Comment: Will do, thanks for everything, I think I can make it work. If not I'll notice you.